# Proving a set (R, *) is a monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

For a set to be a monoid, it must be associative and must have an identity element.
I've proved that is it associative but don't know how to prove that it has a identity element.

> 1. Let $\mathbb{R}^3$ be the set of all ordered triples of numbers, and let $\otimes$ be the binary operation on $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined such that
>      $$\left(x_1, y_1, z_1\right) \otimes \left(x_2, y_2, z_2\right) = \left(x_1x_2, x_1y_2+y_1z_2, z_1z_2\right)$$
>      for all $\left(x_1, y_1, z_1\right), \left(x_2, y_2, z_2\right) \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Prove that $\left(\mathbb{R}^3, \otimes\right)$ is a monoid. What is the identity element of this monoid? Is the monoid $\left(\mathbb{R}^3, \otimes\right)$ a group?

Comment: It is not hard to see from the expression that the identity element must be of the form $(1,y,1)$. For what value of $y=y_1$ does one have $1y_2+yz_2=y_2$ for all $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$? Does one also have $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\otimes(1,y,1)=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ for this value of $y$ and all $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that there exist a tuple $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ such that $(x_1,y_1,z_1)\otimes (x_2,y_2,z_2)=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ for all $(x_1,y_1,z_1)\in \mathbb{R}^3$. Looking at the first coordinate of your formula we get $x_1x_2=x_1$ for all $x_1$ and this implies that $x_2=1$. In the same way, but looking at the third coordinate, we get $z_1z_2=z_1$ for all $z_1$, so that $z_2=1$. Now, it is easy get $y_2=0$. Since the law it is not commutative you need to check the other way around. This is an easy computation and it shows that $(1,0,1)$ is indeed the identity.

This monoid is not a group. For example the element $(0,0,0)$ does not have an inverse because if $(x,y,z)$ were such inverse then $(0,0,0)\otimes (x,y,z)$ would be $(1,0,1)$ but $(0,0,0)\otimes (x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$.

Comment: So does that also mean it's a group?

Comment: To see that it is not a group you can observe that $(0,0,0)\otimes(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ for all $(x,y,z)$ so that $(0,0,0)$ does not have inverse.

Comment: Is there a reason for using (0,0,0)? Why not invert (1,0,1)?

Comment: In a group every element is invertible. The element $(0,0,0)$ is not invertible in your monoid. In the other hand $(1,0,1)$ is his own inverse (and therefore it is invertible$.

Comment: OK. So that means (R,*) is not a group?

Comment: No, It is not a group. I have edited the answer to include these observations.

Answer (score 7):

Looks suspiciously like the set of matrices
\begin{equation} 
\begin{bmatrix} 
x & y\\
0 & z
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation} 
under matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

I would try something like $(1,0,1)$ and $(1,1,1)$. In first and third coordinates the operation is just mulitplication, so the unit will be $1$ there.

But the clearest if you write it up:

$(x,y,z)\otimes (1,b,1) = (x,y,z)\ $   and solve it for $b$.
You can use specific $(x,y,z)$'s, e.g. plug in $(1,0,0)$, etc.

Answer (score 3):

So for $(e,f,g)$ to be an identity element means in particular that $$(x,y,z)\otimes (e,f,g)=(x,y,z)$$
for all $x,y,z$. Comparing coordinates one gets $xe=x$, $xf+yg=y$ and $zg=z$.

Solving this and checking this and checking which elements satisfy the reverse identity is left as an exercise for you.

Comment: How did you get $xf + yg = y$  ?

Comment: @AdegokeA This is just comparison of the second coordinate of the result of this "strange" multiplication and $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: But should it not be $xe = x, yf =y$ and $zg = z$ ?

Comment: @AdegokeA No, see the definition of $\otimes$ in the question.

Comment: It says a binary operation. I thought ⊗ meant multiplication. Those the ⊗ operator have a different function?

Comment: @AdegokeA Read the exercise! It is a "multiplication", but not the ordinary one. As Andreas Caranti mentions in another answer it can be regarded as the matrix multiplication of $2\times 2$-matrices.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you need to find $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ s.t. $x_1x_2=x_1$, $x_1y_2+y_1z_2=y_1$ and $z_1z_2=z_1$. From this it follows that $x_2=z_2=1$. And $y_2=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The identity element is (1,0,1)

Also 
$(x,y,z)^{-1}=(x^{-1},\frac{-y}{zx},z^{-1})$,
if $x\not=0,z\not=0$

Comment: This formula makes no sense for $x=0$ (or $z$).

Comment: Is it really a group?

Comment: If you get rid of the zeros in x and z, then yes.